# MS Word header level 4 numbers is wrong

Tags: microsoft-word

Header numbering is fine for the first 3 levels.

> 1
> 1.1
> 1.2 2
> 2.1
> 2.2
> 2.2.1
> 2.2.2

etc

But, my level 4 headers are not of format A.B.C.D - only D, where D starts at 1 and increments throughout the document, not resetting when higher header levels are encountered.

E.g, if I were to add a level 4 at the end of the example shown,I would expect it to be 2.2.2.1, but I see only 1.

I have searched and tried things such as [this](https://wordknowhow.blog/2013/05/20/how-to-fix-multilevel-list-in-word/), but they are all very complicated.

Is there a ***simple*** way to fix my problem?   MS Office pro 2016, if it makes any difference.

[Upadate]

[image]

Comment: It looks as if you need to select “Heading 4” in the “Link level to style” dropdown

Comment: That, combined with @Emily's answer solved it. Thank you so very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check whether the level 4 shown correct in Define new Multilevel list?
The first 3 numbers should include level numbers form level 1, level 2 and level 3.

[image]

If the settings are OK, but the issue still persists, please put the cursor after level number, press Left arrow (←), then press Ctrl+ Shift+ S to open Apply Styles, make sure it use a correct style.

[image]

Comment: Still not working, sorry. I added a screenshot to the question. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: As per @Yokki's comment "`It looks as if you need to select “Heading 4” in the “Link level to style” dropdown`", when combined with your answer, it works! Thank you extremely much